# Strip/remove values in array at certain indices

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have one array like so:

```
peoples = ['dick', 'jane', 'harry', 'debra', 'hank', 'frank' .... ]
```

And one containing keys like so:

```
keys  = [1, 6, 3, 12 .... ]
```

Now I could write something like this:

```
var peoplesStripedOfKeyPostions = [];

for(i = 0; i < peoples.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
        if( i !== keys[j]){
            peoplesStripedOfKeyPostions.push( peoples[i] );
        }
    }        
}
```

If you can't tell, I'm need to produce an array of people that is stripped of people at certain positions defined in array keys. I know there has to be a nifty and efficient way to do this, but I certainly can't think of it. (array management not my forte).

Do you know a better way to do this? (If I get multiple working answers, jsperf determines the winner.)

Comment: Do you need a copy, or can you delete items from `peoples`?

Comment: I need a copy, preserving the original.

Comment: Keys are in no particular order

Comment: I believe you mean "stripped" (clothing) not "striped" (zebra)

Comment: Underscore is allowed? in that case:

\_.filter(peoples, function(person, index) {return !\_.include(keys, index)});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
people.filter(function(x,i){return badIndices.indexOf(i)==-1})
```

This will become inefficient if the `badIndices` array is large. A more efficient (albeit less elegant) version would be:

```
var isBadIndex = {};
badIndices.forEach(function(k){isBadIndex[k]=true});

people.filter(function(x,i){return !isBadIndex[i]})
```

(*note: you cannot use a variable named `keys` because that is a builtin function*)

Comment: will that alter `peoples` or return a value I can set a copy off of?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: it will return a copy of the `people` array without modifying the original array

Comment: +1 for `filter()`. A note that it appears to be unsupported in IE < 9.

Comment: @ninjagecko I really could use the opposite actually, I tried simply reverting to `return badIndices.indexOf(i) !== -1` but oddly enough it achieved the same list.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: it can never be the case that `==` and `!=` return different lists (except in a handful of edge cases, almost certainly not the issue); make sure you are properly printing/logging the right variables.

Comment: I have double checked everything, and its certainly the case.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: sorry, I meant "it can never be the case that == and != return the same list"; you were asserting that they achieved the same list, they ought to return a different list

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete the entries from the array by index, then gather up whoever is left.

```
keys.forEach(function(i) { delete people[i]; });

peopleRemaining = Object.keys(people).map(function(i) { return people[i]; });
```

Note that this modifies the original `people` array.

Comment: I don't think this would work, because once a deletion occurs as `people[i]` the indices of the `people` array shifts.

Comment: Deleting an array index just leaves a hole because array indices are merely properties. If you want to shift, you need to use the `splice` method.

Comment: I did no know that. Interesting.

Comment: Think about it: You can use anything as an array index. `count['apple'] = 3;` for example. If you did a `delete count['apple'];` what would it mean to "shift" the remaining entries?

Comment: well if I was to use something like `count['apple']` I am not in an array, I am in an object. And objects in javascript do not have indices. `count['apple']` is really a dynamic way to write `count.apple`, while `count[4]` cannot be `count.4`

Comment: What about `count['@!#']`? You can't write `count.@!#` either. Section 15.4 of [the JavaScript spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) says that Arrays are just Objects with a special `length` property that tracks the highest integer-valued property. Section 15.4 also talks about "sparse"ness, so clearly it is legal to have holes.

Comment: `count['@!#']` its still and object not an array. You still have `.length` but there are not position indices.

Comment: Call it whatever you like. I know what the spec says.

Comment: Its not about the name, its about the absence of position indices.

Comment: Whatever. JavaScript supports sparse arrays. You can delete elements from the middle of an array and it just leaves a hole. That's why the above code works.

Comment: And that is both cool, and informative. And why I upvoted your answer.