# Javascript - How to delete items from an array at given indices

Tags: javascript, splice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strip/remove values in array at certain indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311467/strip-remove-values-in-array-at-certain-indices)

How do I remove a set of elements from an array at given indices using Javascript.

Say I have an index array:

`var indices = [0, 1, 3]`.

I want to remove elements from another array at these given `indices`.  That other array happens to be:

`var cars = ["Cow", "Dog", "Ferrari", "Monkey", "Ford"]`.

So, after deletion I want "Cow", "Dog", "Monkey" to be removed from `cars` array

I have tried the `splice` way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){
   cars.splice(indices[i], 1);
}
```

But this code happens to change the indices of the `cars` array every time an item is spliced!

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: U don't want array index to be changed right ?

Comment: @ameyarote That's right.

Comment: So when an element is removed, that array slot should just be empty? The values to its right shouldn't move one slot left? Creating holes in the array?

Comment: @Vineeth - please refer my opinion stated below it may help U..
because deleting an array element means u will loose index, if U don't want that use name changing convention as stated below

Comment: I disagree that this question be marked as 'duplicate'. The duplicate question link in my opinion is entirely different in the context of the question what I have asked. I would want the original array be 'cleaned' up of unwanted elements whose indices are specified in another array but the OP of the duplicate question link wants a copy of the original array. Voting for reopen so that I can make an effort to post my solution

Answer (score 3):

You can start from the last element:

```
for(var i = indices.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
   cars.splice(indices[i], 1);
}
```

Comment: It may be obvious to some of us, but an explanation for the OP might help explain why it's necessary to loop backwards

Comment: beat me to it, the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EX3Hm/) I was making for my answer for the OP if he cares.

Comment: I guess Problem remains same where index of array is changed. Index of array should not be changed as what is required

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var cars = ["Cow", "Dog", "Ferrari", "Monkey", "Ford"];
console.log(cars);

cars.each(function(val, index){
    // You can use jQuery inArray also.  
    //For Ex: if(jQuery.inArray(index, indices)){........}
    if(val=="Cow" || val=="Dog" || val=="Monkey" ){
        cars.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
console.log(cars);
```

JAVASCRIPT: Then use `.forEach` instead of `.each`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete` to remove elements without modifying the indices.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
delete a[2]; // deletes '3'
console.log(a); // prints [1, 2, undefined, 4, 5]
```

You can use `splice()` to remove elements and shift the rest to fill out the removed indices

```
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
b.splice(2, 1); // deletes '3' and shifts the rest to left
console.log(b); // prints [1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Using delete will create a whole in the array ,and using splice will disturb the index of an array.

Comment: @ameyarote What do you mean a "hole in the array"? It "removes" the items, yet keeps their original indexes. It depends on how the array will be used after this operation.

Comment: @ameyarote - I assume the OP wants to use the array items like before, for ex: an item addressed as `a[3]`, should be addressable as `a[3]` even after deleting some item(s) before it. Using `delete` will let him do that.

Comment: @techfoobar - I mean to say that instead of deleting an element and reusing that element is not better than directly assigning EXAMPLE cars[indices[i]] = "Deleted"; i.e. assigning id convention to array index.

Answer (score -1):

Splice method deletes item completely, So As u said  "But this code happens to change the indices of the cars object every time an item is spliced!" it will strictly remove element. You can use naming convention id as "Deleted" or any familiar naming id instead of removing (deleting) element if you want to maintain same array index

for(var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++){
   cars[indices[i]] = "Deleted";
}

With this You can maintain same array index as you required.

Please can you explain why -1 ? its not what deserve, or Justify it.